# IIS: Feature has been locked or read only when changing authentication

Tags: .net, iis

We are currently migrating .net websites from 2008 to 2012. Most of these websites use anonymous authentication on the root, and forms authentication on an admin folder.

I noticed that I'm unable to change these permissions in IIS. I keep receiving that the feature has been locked or is read only. I have checked my web.config to ensure there is no  section that would block this. Converting that subfolder to a separate website is not an option.

Comment: Do you own that Windows Server 2012 machine fully? You can easily remove the locking if you have administrator access to it. If you don't, then you have to talk to the server administrators.

Comment: Do you mean under Feature Delegation? Currently I have read/write for all authentication types except Digest (which is read only). Also under Configuration Editor  system.webServer/security/authentication/windows is seems unlocked (because the option is Lock Section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here.

1.Store  section in applicationhost.config file by using location element. Open IIS Manager, high-light your site, navigate to Content view, right-click the particular page, click Switch to Feature View, click Authentication icon, enable/disable Windows Authentication.

2.Adjust the Feature Delegation settings. Open IIS Manager, high-light the sever name on Connections pane in IIS manager, click Feature Delegation icon under Management section on the Home pane, high-light authentication- Windows/Anonymous, then click Read/Write on the right Actions pane.

Answer taken from - https://forums.iis.net/t/1170130.aspx?IIS+7+Windows+Authentication+This+feature+has+been+locked+or+Read+Only

Comment: For me, doing step 2 does not seem to allow 'Forms Authentication' to be disabled, even though read/write is set. This is true only on sub-folders, the site folder works as expected.